# D3 force layout text label overlapping

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a hard time positioning text label on my force chart. They are overlapping each other, and I could not figure out how to fix it. And I've tried many solutions from online, none of them works well. Could you please help me take a look?

Here are the code for my text labels:

```
    var node_text = node_textNew.append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "text_note")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", -0.5)
    .attr('background-color', '#fff')
    .attr("x",    function(d, i) { return circleWidth + 5; })
    .attr("y",  function(d, i) { if (i>0) { return circleWidth + 0 } else { return 8 } })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name});
```

Here is how it looks right now: [image]

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425268/d3js-automatic-labels-placement-to-avoid-overlaps-force-repulsion) should help.

Comment: I've tried. It's not working on my graph. The labels will be too far away from the circles.

Comment: @EllieZhu, that's a lot of labels in a tight space.  What alternatives exist besides moving the labels away from the circles?

Comment: One of the alternative will be not showing the labels at the same time. It will be less crowded, but I still have to figure out how to move them around.

Comment: On option i can suggest is show the labels on hover...that should reduce the overlaps.

Comment: Can you maybe show a running example?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729.
Here the author introduces a way when a label is placed near a node using another force layout.

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution I have found us to use the center of a nodes Voronoi cell as the anchor for a label. This gives you the optimal spacing provided by your graph.

An example of this is seen in:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6909318